# Which Continuous Integration library to use?

Tags: java, comparison, continuous-integration, agile, cruisecontrol

I've worked with **Cruise Control** as the CI framework in my last project.
Any recommendations on some other tools?

(Not that i found CruiseControl lacking, just wanted to know if someone did some comparisons)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We have had great success with [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/). It is easy to install and configure, has a great range of plugins and a good web user interface. The checkstyle and cobertura code coverage plugins are two that we use.

Comment: For more on "CC vs Hudson", see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604385/what-is-the-difference-between-hudson-and-cruisecontrol-for-java-projects

Answer (score 9):

JetBrain's [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is pretty cool.

Comment: +1 for TeamCity. Much better than CCnet in both installation/configuration as well as general usability.

Comment: +1 for TeamCity. It's usability is simply incredible.

Answer (score 7):

We use [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/).

For a rather extensive feature matrix of the various major CI servers, have a look at: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/CI+Feature+Matrix

Comment: +1 for link to feature matrix...thx.

Answer (score 5):

Since I've switched from Ant to Maven as my build system, [Continuum](http://continuum.apache.org/) is the obvious choice.  It's very clean and offers all the features that I need.

Answer (score 5):

I second Peter's recommendation for [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org).  Continuum and Hudson are both very easy to set-up and use (compared to CruiseControl), but Hudson offers a lot more functionality.  If you're interested, I've [previously written](http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/05/09/why-are-you-still-not-using-hudson/) about why I would choose Hudson.

TeamCity, with its [pre-tested commit functionality](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/delayed_commit.html), is also a good choice if you can live with the limitations of a [free Professional Licence](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/buy/buy.jsp#professional) (maximum of 20 users and 20 build configurations).

Answer (score 2):

We use LuntBuild which works perfectly with maven.

In addition, Lunbuild offers a good deal of granularity for access control.  I haven't used too many CI tools, but that was the main reason my company switched to Luntbuild from Cruise Control.  We wanted to give clients access to the build server so they could pull daily builds, etc, but we couldn't have them accessing other clients' builds.

Answer (score 2):

We use TFS 2008 which works for us because we're pretty much an all MS environment... however, I've also used [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/), which has more features than just about anything else I've seen and would be especially useful in environments where you were using a mix of technologies (multiple SCM's for example).

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2008 is pretty good. It has continuous integration built in to TFS build.

Answer (score 1):

TFS 2008 is pretty good

As are CruiseControl and Nant

Have a look at [CI factory](http://www.cifactory.org/joomla/), which requires minimal configuration