# What is the difference between Hudson and CruiseControl for Java projects?

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins, cruisecontrol

I think the title sums it up.  I just want to know why one or the other is better for continous integration builds of Java projects from Svn.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As a long time CruiseControl committer **and** someone who has never used Hudson I'm pretty biased, but my take on it is:

Hudson is much easier to get up and running (in large part from a nice web interface) and has a very active plugin development community.

CruiseControl has support from lots of [3rd party stuff](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CC/3rdPartyCCStuff) and has the benefit of doing some neat tricks with the xml configuration like plugin preconfiguration and include.projects which lets you version the configuration information with the project.

If you're only going to have a few builds I think Hudson is the clear winner. If you're going to have lots -- and don't mind the xml -- then I think CruiseControl's xml configuration tricks become a real strength.

Answer (score 117):

I agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604385/what-is-the-difference-between-hudson-and-cruisecontrol-for-java-projects/604419#604419), but wanted to add a few points.

In short, **Hudson** (update: **[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)**) is likely the better choice now. First and foremost because creating and configuring jobs ("projects" in CC vocabulary) is just *so much faster* through Hudson's web UI, compared to editing CruiseControl's XML configuration file (which we used to keep in version control just to keep track of it better). The latter is not especially difficult - it simply is slower and more tedious.

CruiseControl has been great, but as noted in Dan Dyer's aptly-named blog post, *[Why are you still not using Hudson?](http://blog.uncommons.org/2008/05/09/why-are-you-still-not-using-hudson/)*, it suffers from being first. (Um, like Britain, if you will, later into the industrial revolution, when others started overtaking it with newer technologies.)

We used CruiseControl heavily and have gradually switched over to Hudson, finally using it exclusively. And *even more* heavily: in the process we've started using the CI server for many other things than before, because setting up and managing Hudson jobs is so handy. (We now have some 40+ jobs in Hudson: the usual build & test jobs for stable and development branches; jobs related to releasing (building installers etc); jobs that run some (experimental) metrics against the codebase; ones that run (slow) UI or integration tests against a specific database version; and so on.)

From this experience I'd argue that even if you have lots of builds, including complicated ones, Hudson is a pretty safe choice because, like CC, you can use it to do *anything*, basically. Just configure your job to run whatever Ant or Maven targets, Unix shell scripts, or Windows .bat scripts, in the order you wish.

As for the 3rd party stuff ([mentioned here by Jeffrey Fredrick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604385/what-is-the-difference-between-hudson-and-cruisecontrol-for-java-projects/605452#605452)) - that is a good point, but my impression is that Hudson is quickly catching up, and that there's already a very large number of [plugins available](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Plugins) for it.

For me, the two things I can name that I miss about CruiseControl are:

1. Its warning emails about broken builds were more informative than those of Hudson. In most cases the root cause was evident from CC's nicely formatted HTML mail itself, whereas with Hudson I usually need to follow the link to Hudson web UI, and click around a little to get the details.
2. The [CruiseControl dashboard](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/dashboard.html) is better suited, out of the box, as an "[information radiator](http://www.agileadvice.com/archives/2005/05/information_rad.html)" (shown on a public monitor, or projected on a wall, so that you can always quickly see the status of all projects). With Hudson's front page, we needed some Greasemonkey tricks to get job rows all nicely green/red.

Minor disclaimer: I haven't been following the CC project closely for the last year or so. (But from a [quick look](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/download.html), it has not changed in any dramatic way.)

**Note** (2011-02-03): Hudson has been [renamed/forked](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/hudsons-future) as [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) (by Hudson creator [Kohsuke Kawaguchi](http://kohsuke.org/2011/01/11/bye-bye-hudson-hello-jenkins/) and others). It looks as if Oracle—which controls the Hudson name—will keep "[Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)" around too, but my personal recommendation is to go with **Jenkins**, no matter what Oracle says.

Comment: Nearly 2 years later, I still agree with everything I wrote above about Hudson ([now being renamed to Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/hudsons-future)). As an addendum, here's some more interesting stuff that I've used Hudson for since then: Launch new AWS EC2 instances from certain AMI and deploy our latest software there straight from version control; Let (tech-savvy) customer control the appearance of a demo application (by editing a config file that the app uses), and also run certain admin operations against the database used by the app (parameterised jobs are useful) ... (cont)

Comment: ... Periodically check that a website or service is up & running; Automatically merge changes from trunk to all work branches shortly after a successful trunk build; and so on. It's worth noting that in most cases Hudson was simply a **front-end** for a shell/Python/etc script, or a more "visible" replacement for a cronjob. But then, it is very good for such purposes! In one project, customer specifically asked for more Hudson jobs for admin/housekeeping operations after I'd done one; for the needs they had it was perfectly adequate, and much handier than logging onto a server to run a script.

Answer (score 30):

My last project, we started off on CruiseControl. Which rocked. Then we moved to Hudson, which rocked even more. The things I liked about Hudson:

- The upstream and downstream projects. So a commit to your data access code will eventually also trigger a build of the presentation layer.
- Easily use an existing project as the starting point of a new one - so if you are in the habit of creating development branches, then making sure these are under continuous integration is a snap.

Comment: +1, totally agree, especially about the second point. We've ended up using Hudson for a lot of stuff because of that (more about it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604385/what-is-the-difference-between-hudson-and-cruisecontrol-for-java-projects/888054#888054)

Comment: Regarding your second point, "[u]s[ing] an existing project as the starting point for a new one" is easy with CC as well: just copy the relevant file(s), make appropriate changes, and register the new project in `ccnet.config`.  Pretty simple really.  "Easily" in this case may just be "easily" in general when considering Jenkins over CC - doing it in a GUI vs. XML files.  TMTOWTDI, but neither is particularly difficult.

Answer (score 15):

One difference is that Hudson is the product of a single genius intellect—Kohsuke Kawaguchi. Because of that, it's consistent, coherent, and rock solid. The downside could be some limitation on the rate of progress. However, Kohsuke is incredibly prolific, so I wouldn't be too worried about that. And, it's extensible, so if there's something Kohsuke doesn't have time for (or doesn't want), you can probably do it yourself.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at both Cruise Control and Hudson but choose Hudson as it was much easier to setup and configure. Hudson seems very widely used these days with regular releases and lots of extensiblity through plugins. I would highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

Hudson is the more user-friendly alternative in my opinion. It can be set up and maintained completely via the web interface (apart from the initial installation of the webapp, of course).

The only way this could be said about CruiseControl is if you count the built-in XML file editor.

Still, having used both, I'd still prefer any one over having no automated build.

Comment: "Still, having used both, I'd prefer any one over having no automated build." +1 for a measure of sanity. Amidst all the rage & high religiosity surrounding Jenkins of late, people too often seem to forget that CC, Jenkins, and other mature CI alternatives are _means to an end_ - the end ultimately being what matters more than the means. Personally, I find CC easy to use even as a relative newcomer to it. Jenkins is fine too. But making such a big deal about one vs. the other is much ado about nothing IMO.

Answer (score 1):

I tried Cruise control...Its good...But documents are fragmented. Dashboard is confusing. Widget creation is also confusing. Never tried hudson. Will try on weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I recently setup Jenkins for building Borland BDS 2006 projects making use of Subversion and I am very happy with it. I never used CruiseControl yet, so I can't compare. Read my blog post for more information.

[Continuous integration of Delphi project with Jenkins](http://www.ictexpertise.com/blog/2016/02/10/continuous-integration-of-delphi-project-with-jenkins/)